# How to add TableRow from xml to TableLayout programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

Im new to Android and I'm trying to add a TableRow, which I already made with xml, to a TableLayout programmatically. I'm getting Force Closes, most are NullPointerExcpetions.

Here's my java class

```
public class DayFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjects_list, container, false);


    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tl);
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tr_row);

            tl.addView(tr); //not working, obviously im missing something

    //xml parsing stuff

            return view;
 }
}
```

This is my layout with the TableLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/table_header" />

        <include android:id="@+id/h_divider"
            layout="@layout/horizontal_divider"/>




    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And the TableRow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tr_row"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_hour"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/vertical_cell_divider" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_subject"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<View
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/vertical_cell_divider" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_start"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_bar"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_end"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</TableRow>
```

I tried lots of different ways to achieve it but still nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace code:

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.tr_row);
tl.addView(tr); //not working, obviously im missing something
```

with

```
View tr = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_layout, null,false);
tl.addView(tr); //not working, obviously im missing something
```

Comment: YES! Thank you very much for solving my problem. Can you also tell me how to add the same view more than once please? The child already has a parent so I can't add it more by just putting tl.addView(tr);

Comment: repeat the code inside for loop. but keep in mind that you have create view array before repeating in for loop. then for every view in array inflate the table_row_layout and add it to Table Layout.

Comment: I just did it like this and it worked

for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
   
  View tr = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subject_row, null, false);
  tl.addView(tr);
  
  }

Comment: @TNR can u please help me i have tablelayout and then tablerow which i added using xml and its working but inside tablerow i have another tablelayout and then tablerow of xml i am facing difficulty to add second tablerow of xml can u please help me